# Omission of “that” (in this text)

Tags: conjunctions, optional-that

I'm trying to re-write published newspaper articles for practice writing.

The original reads:

> We seem to forget **that** we all have some rights over the government. The government has come into being primarily to serve the needs of the
>   citizen, which he as an individual or as a member of a small community
>   cannot take care. It is important we have an accountable government.

I wrote:

> We seem to forget **that** we all have some rights over the government. The government came* into being primarily to serve the needs of
>   a citizen, which he as an individual or as a member of a small community cannot take care. It is important **that** we have an
>   accountable government.

I really don't understand why "that" is correct the first sentence and not second?

Comment: It's optional in both sentences.  Your version is fine.

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct in the second?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Because "that" is missing in that _published_ article

Comment: it's an ellipsis

Comment: @snailboat: May as well make that an answer....

Comment: @NathanTuggy I would, but it's too short.  The mods here frown on short answers and convert them to comments anyway, so we'd just go full circle :-)

Comment: The bigger, and more important, question is: Why did you change the "has come" to "came" in the 2nd sentence?

Comment: Not the question you were asking, but "take care" in your second sentence should be "take care of." (I would reword, and say something like "provide for".)

Comment: @F.E.:  It seems quite reasonable to change this to simple past. The government came into being some time ago; it is not still coming into being. I don't think this is a big deal, and I'm not surprised the OP had no qualms about it.

Answer (score 9):

The original text:

> *We seem to forget **that** we all have some rights over the government. The government has come into being primarily to serve the needs of the citizen, which [sic] he as an individual or as a member of a small community cannot take care. It is important **(that)** we have an accountable government.*

Your question:

> I really don't understand why "that" is correct the first sentence and not second?

Let's get this straight: *that* is **optional** in both sentences (as said in comments under your question).

There are several cases that ***that*** could be omitted. (Some people call this "omission", some call this "ellipsis".) Your text is an example of two of them. The first one is an omission of *that* after a reporting verb. The second is an omission of *that* after an adjective.

#### *that*: omission after reporting verbs

This is common after verbs such as *say*, *tell*, *learn*, *discover*, *find*, *know*, *feel*, *think*, etc.

> *He **said** (that) he felt better.*
>   *She **told** us (that) she was sorry and left the room.*
>   *We **learned** (that) the locals believed photographs would steal their souls.*
>   *We **discovered** (that) they had stolen the bag.*
>   *He was surprised to **find** (that) they had arrived at the bank.*

Your first *that* falls into this category of usage.

> *We seem to **forget (that)** we all have some rights over the government.*

Also note that you cannot drop *that* after some reporting verbs such as *shout* and *reply* (though some dictionaries seem to suggest that *that* after *reply* is optional, e.g. ['reply (that)'
 in this dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/reply_1)).

> *She **shouted that** she was leaving now.* (NOT <del>*She shouted she ...*</del>)

#### *that*: omission after adjectives

In the pattern *be* + adjective + *that*-clause, particularly when the adjective is related to feelings or opinions, *that* can be (and usually is) omitted. Adjectives commonly used like this are *glad*, *sure*, *sorry*, *afraid*, *surprised*, *pleased*, *important*, *necessary*, *essential*, etc.

> *I'm **glad (that)** she made it.*
>   *I'm **sure (that)** he can handle that.*
>   *We were **afraid (that)** none of us would survive.*
>   *We were **surprised (that)** they came.*
>   *It's **important (that)** you understand.*
>   *It's **necessary (that)** we talk with them now.*

Your second *that* falls into this category of usage.

> *It is **important (that)** we have an accountable government.*

---

#### Caution: *that* is required if your subject is a clause

Note that if you use a clause as the subject in a sentence, you cannot omit *that*, e.g., *[That we'd survived the trip was something of a miracle](http://www.fieldandstream.com/photos/gallery/kentucky/2007/11/baja-bike-fishing-desert-back-motorcycle)*. This sentence has two clauses *we'd survived the trip* and *that was something of a miracle*. When we write it as a single sentence, with the first clause as the subject of the sentence, we must use *that*, i.e., ***That*** we'd survived the trip was something of a miracle. (This type of *that*-clause is also known as "content clause", as Araucaria pointed out in a comment below.)

---

#### Bonus: *'that'*: not too many, not too few

Because *that* is optional, it's a fair question to ask: when it's possible, should we or should we not omit it? In order words, how should we decide when to omit *that* (when it's possible)?

Unfortunately, there is no quick and dirty rule. It's easy to imagine that someone would omit *that* whenever they can, whereas someone else would keep *that* whenever possible, and most people would be somewhere between the two extremes. The bottom line is you have to use your own discretion.

However, there is a good rule of thumb: do not omit *that* if ambiguity results.

These examples could help explain why:

> *He said **that** after the show was over the committee would award the winner the medal.*
>   = The committee would award the winner after the show.
>
> *He said after the show was over **that** the committee would award the winner the medal.*
>   = He said that after the show.
>
> *He said after the show was over the committee would award the winner the medal.*
>   **Ambiguity alert!** Did he say it after the show? Or would the committee award the winner after the show?

Also, keep in mind that too many (of *that*s) is as bad as too few.

If you believe that keeping *that* is always safer, you could fall into this kind of trap:

> *He said that after the show was over and it had been officially announced that the committee would award the winner the medal.*
>   <sub>(This is arguably ungrammatical, even, if the writer tries to elaborate a bit more of the same example above.</sub>

Can you see the ambiguity? ;-)

Comment: I would have added a big shout out to http://www.englishgrammar.org/omission/ if I had referred to it when constructing this answer.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I don't know. Is that page good? If you implied that I based my answer on that page, I have to say you're mistaken. (This kind of information is all over the web and is common in textbooks. Personally, I doubt how 'original' a page on the web is.) -- Anyway, the reader can find that page via your comment.

Comment: @DamkerngT. +1 You could helpfully add that when a content clause appears at the beginning of a sentence the *that* is mandatory. For example: *That you succeeded does not surprise me* versus **You succeeded does not surprise me*.