# 'The next time you are going to' or 'The next time {when/if} you go' - which is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, tense

> The next time you are going to Agra don't worry about being late.

Shouldn't that sentence be:

> The next time **when/ if** you **go** to Agra don't worry about being late.

I believe a connector is required after *time*. *The next time* and *present continuous* sounds strange to a non native speaker.

Is the only difference is the formal and the informal way of writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "connector" after *time*. But it's been omitted.

Both

> The next time *[that] you are going to Agra* don't worry about being late.

and

> The next time *[that] you go to Agra* don't worry about being late.

are idiomatic and grammatical.

Notice that the relative pronoun *that* can be omitted without changing the meaning. I've indicated the relative clause in *italics*.

See Cambridge on [Relative pronouns](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns), including *Relative pronouns: that* and *No relative pronoun*, the latter of which talks about omitting the relative pronoun.

See [Omission of that](http://www.englishgrammar.org/omission/) on the website *English Grammar*.

Related: [Omission of "that" in this text](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56579/omission-of-that-in-this-text), which seems to be partially based on/inspired by *English Grammar* (the first result in a Google search for 'Omission of that').